# Is it possible to view a list of all documents written by myself in Confluence?

Tags: confluence

Alright, I wrote many documents in Confluence. Now I want to reread one of my document, but it's in a long list of documents written by my team.

I think it would be faster to find the document if I can view a list of all the documents written by myself, but is it possible? How?

Answer (score 2):

Go to "People" link in your Confluence site and search for user name. Click on your name returned in search result and it will take you to your "Activity" page. Below link is from Confluence latest version.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/search-the-people-directory-201706.html#SearchthePeopleDirectory-Searchforpeople

Comment: Thanks! "People" shows all my recent activities, which include many items I don't need to know. Is there any more concrete way to only view the documents written by myself?

Answer (score 1):

In a Confluence page click the + icon and select Other macros:

Select the Content by User macro [image: Content by User macro image]

Add your username and select yourself.
Then save and view the page. You should see a list of every page created by you (or any user entered).

**Note:** This will also show you images uploaded seperately, so you may have to filter a bit.